# False "Object does not fit into print volume" warning from OctoPrint

Tags: octoprint

Octoprint warns me that the objects do not fit into the print volume. I noticed that this happens after a power-off cycle. Since I was overly anxious until today, I always uploaded the GCode file again and it didn't complain any more.

Of course, always uploading the files again is also error prone. So today I gave it a try and simply started to print the object. As far as I can tell, it prints nicely.

> Image: Octoprint saying something like "Object does not fit into print volume" in German

[image: Object does not fit into print volume]

**Is this a known bug in OctoPrint? Are my files really damaged after a power off cycle?**

The values (0.00, -3.00, 0.00) seem to be constant in this error message, no matter what object I want to print.

I'm using OctoPrint in the PrusaPrint flavor and I'm running version 1.3.10 (hopefully a recent version, since I usually update). I generate the G-Code with Slic3r.

Comment: The chance of corrupting a gcode file during upload is extremely small.  If you are in fact getting errors *there*,  you may want to check your connectors and the quality of power supply for the printer circuit board.   But as the answer points out, you don't actually have a problem with volume dimensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the purging that Slic3r PE adds, the broad line of filament at the edge of the sheet. That is outside the official print volume, which triggers this error.

The G-Code generated by Slic3r PE at the start of the file contains the following lines:

```
G1 Y-3.0 F1000.0 ; go outside print area
G92 E0.0
G1 X60.0 E9.0  F1000.0 ; intro line
M73 Q0 S174
M73 P0 R173
G1 X100.0 E12.5  F1000.0 ; intro line
G92 E0.0
```

You can see that it explicitly goes to -3 on the Y axis, and then extrudes two times on a line along the X axis.

The model size detection is labeled as beta in the settings dialog. It's not very reliable at detecting stuff like this purging line outside the boundaries.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](/a/8267) is correct, it's normal for Prusa printers to purge at -3 mm on the Y axis.

This answer is an addition that describes how to get rid of the error.

1. Open Octoprint web UI
2. Go to `Settings` -> `Printer Profiles`
3. Find active profile, click on the pen icon next to it (`Edit Profile`)
4. Go to `Print bed and build volume`
5. Tick `Custom bounding box`
6. Enter -3 to `Y Coordinates` `Min` input box
7. Hit `Confirm`